# Error in upset_data : unused argument (nsets = 5) What could be causing this and how coul I fix the issue?

Tags: r, dataframe, upsetr, upsetplot, complex-upset

I am very new to R and I would like to make UpSet plot of peptides.

I have five lists (sets) in .txt format (ID_list_vysledok_pos_vs_healthy_files.txt, ID_list_vysledok_pos_neg_files.txt, ID_list_vysledok_New_vs_Old_collumn_files.txt, ID_list_vysledok_neg_vs_healthy_files.txt, ID_list_vysledok_Coated_vs_Liquid_junction_files.txt)

Each .txt file is just list of peptides in this format:  [List of peptides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxat3.png)

I was following step by step instructions by this link :  http://genomespot.blogspot.com/2017/09/upset-plots-as-replacement-to-venn.html

The code is working without problems until I want to make the graph with : `upset(res2, nsets=5)`

It gives me following error: `Error in upset_data(data, intersect, mode = mode, encode_sets = encode_sets,  :  unused argument (nsets = 5)`

The res2 dataframe looks like it should be looking to make this graph : [View(res2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZpt.png)

I think the problem is trivial and sets may not be properly defined (but in the link I was following it is working), but I was not able to fix this...

I installed these libraries : library(plyr), library(reshape2), library(UpSetR)

Just to be sure I will provide the code (same as in link): [Photo of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DaPH.png)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be mixing up packages. You are trying to use `upset_data` function from `ComplexUpset` package, but passing `nsets` argument which works with `upset` from `UpSetR` package. I would recommend taking a closer look at which functions you use. If you want to use both UpSetR and ComplexUpset, you can distinguish them with `ComplexUpset::upset` and `UpSetR::upset`.

Comment: Thank you, I already solved this problem and it was the problem you suggested. I restarted R and installed the packages again and the same code was working perfectly. Thank you anyway.